# Laravel : user didn't sign in the system for 15 days then sent mail

Tags: php, laravel, email

So i want sent mail to user if the user didn't sign in the system for 15 days. How to implement that inside code. I have attache my code here.

```
 if ($user->last_sign_in) {
       $ableToSendMail = true;
     }
```

Comment: Is this run inside a scheduled console command?

Comment: YES SIR Im using command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Carbon` to parse your current date and compare it with `diffInDays`

```
use Carbon\Carbon

$last_sign_in = Carbon::parse($user->last_sign_in);
$DeferenceInDays = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->diffInDays($last_sign_in);

if($DeferenceInDays > 15){
    $ableToSendMail = true;
}
```

by using a query.

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(15);
$users = User::where('last_sign_in', '<=', $date)->get();
```

Comment: thank you sir, its working. if i take the DeferenceInDays frm db means can uh @Dilip Hirapara

Comment: Yes, I can. Can you show me your query code so I can customise it as per your requirement.

Comment: the mail should send after few days. The days will take frm db $mail->days